# How to convert 3 or more LiveData. into a single Flow in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

The view model has 3 live data coming in from 3 different api calls. Now, I want to display all the data together as different cards in a list in the recycler view.

What would be the best way to do this ?

Currently I'm using MediatorLiveData, but now I need to have 4 different api calls, which would make 4 live data objects. Therefore, I'm trying to use kotlin flow for this problem. How can I combine the. 4 different Live Data coming in from different UseCases into a single Flow object and then collect it in the Fragment ?

Following is the method, where I'm trying to combine the 3 live data using combine method :

```
private val flow1 = pojo1UseCase.data.asFlow()
private val flow2 = pojo2UseCase.data.asFlow()
private val flow3 = pojo3UseCase.data.asFlow()


suspend fun combine() {
    flow1.combine(flow2) { f1, f2 ->
        listOf(f1.right(), f2.right())
    }.combine(flow3) { f1, f3 ->
        listOf(f1, f3.right())
    }.collect { list ->
        list.forEach {
            ba = it as? Pojo1
            oc = it as? Pojo2
            sd = it as? Pojo3
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling collect here just for testing purpose, but i intend to call collect method in fragment.
Can someone share a better way to do similar thing ?

Comment: Does each source LiveData only return one useful result? i.e., can you just get the first result from each?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Each pojo1UseCase.data is actually an object like this: LiveData<Either<Failure, SomePojo>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is simple and you are only expecting one value from each LiveData, `combine` should be fine, but you could use the variant that takes three arguments.

Also, since it's just another cold Flow, it can be in a simple property. The cold Flow would be backed by the LiveDatas, so the values retrieved aren't lost if something comes along after the results are received and collects the Flow. A suspend function is only necessary if you are collecting it.

```
val combined: Flow<List<Any>> = 
    combine(flow1, flow2, flow3) { a, b, c -> listOf(a, b, c) }
```

But I would recommend a class to hold your objects so you don't have to cast them when they come out.

```
data class MyResult(pojo1: Pojo1, pojo2: Pojo2, pojo3: Pojo3)

val combined: Flow<MyResult> = combine(flow1, flow2, flow3, ::MyResult)
```

Since there is nothing cancelling these Flows automatically, if you make a suspend function that collects them, I think you need to use `first()` or it will suspend indefinitely.

```
suspend fun combine() = with(combined.first()) {
    ba = pojo1
    oc = pojo2
    sd = pojo3
}
```

Or instead you could define your flow with `take(1)` to allow it to automatically complete on the first result.

```
val combined: Flow<MyResult> = combine(flow1, flow2, flow3, ::MyResult).take(1)
```

Edit, based on comment:

If you want to collect them indefinitely, you can start that internally, or you can create a function that you will call once to start collection. You should not use a suspend function, because whichever coroutine calls it would be stuck on the `collect()` call forever. It should just be a regular function that launches its own coroutine to collect it.

```
init { 
    combined.onEach {
        with(it) {
            ba = pojo1
            oc = pojo2
            sd = pojo3
        }
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}

// or:

fun startCombining() {
    combined.onEach {
        with(it) {
            ba = pojo1
            oc = pojo2
            sd = pojo3
        }
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Comment: The above answer works great and I am using first() to get the elements, however after that, the flow will closes, which is a limitation to the solution. Can we keep the flow open to new elements. How can I use collect here ?

Comment: If you want to continuously collect them, you shouldn't do it with a suspend function that collects forever and never returns. Instead, launch an internal coroutine to do the collection. See the edit.